# How to exclude calculating cells in a formula that contain "0"?

Tags: excel

I'm getting the average % change among an array of cells (A1-D1). Cell A11 is `=COUNT(1:1)-1` (to get the number of cells that actually contain anything). The formula I'm using to get the average is `=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(B1,,,,A11)/OFFSET(A1,,,,A11))/A11-1,0)` (someone on a different forum helped me out with that one). This works fine for the most part. The problem is that some of the cells--let's say A1 and B1--contain "0". This results in a "Divide by Zero" error. Is there a way to exclude any cell that contains zero from the calculation? Thanks!

Comment: maybe you can replace the value of 0 by 1, it wont affect the division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this formula to ignore the cells that would give a #DIV/0! error

```
=SUM(IFERROR(OFFSET(B1,,,,A11)/OFFSET(A1,,,,A11),0))/SUM(--ISNUMBER(OFFSET(B1,,,,A11)/OFFSET(A1,,,,A11)))
```

IFERROR in the numerator sets the result of any divisions by zero to zero.

ISNUMBER in denominator gives a TRUE for all divisions which are not divisions by zero, and this is converted to a '1' by the --.

The formula has to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

EDIT

```
=SUM(IFERROR(OFFSET(B1,,,,A11)/OFFSET(A1,,,,A11),0))/COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1,,,,A11),"<>0")
```

gives the same result and is shorter (note that if the last number i.e. D1 is zero, you don't get a #DIV/0! error).

Like the question, this assumes there are no empty cells between numbers - otherwise you couldn't use COUNT and OFFSET to get the range.

[image]